# nsdate formatter returning nil, how to set date formate in mm-dd-yy AM/PM

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i have a date string like this:

```
Printing description of dateTimeString:
2014-07-15 04:15:00
```

i am trying to convert it in 07-15-2014 4:15 AM.
the code i am using:

```
NSString *dateTimeString = appointment.start_time;;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];//date is nil
```

can some please help me setting date in desired formate.

thanks

Comment: Does that format string match the input string?

Comment: thanks for the hint let me try with am pm formate

Comment: Your input string format should be exactly the same as desired date format.

Comment: Well the real hint is that you need to use 2 date formatters: string -> date -> string (and am/pm was not part of the hint).

Comment: thanks i have been able to convert as desired using two date formates. however am/pm did not appended auomatically. i am trying to use HH:mm a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct format strings:

```
NSString *dateTimeString = appointment.start_time;;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];
```

This will create the correct `NSDate` object.

About formatting it to present to you user, I can not stress enough that you should **not** use a static format nut ask the system to give you the correct format.

```
NSString *formatttedDate = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle] timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

But if you need just use the specific date format:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a"];
```

This format will give you the date you want.

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my problem.Can i control am/pm to AM/PM

Comment: That is depending on your local, But I can not stress enough that you should not use static date formats.

Answer (score -1):

i think this helps you

```
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy||HHmmss"];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *retStr = [format stringFromDate:now];
```

Comment: This does not match any of the date formats asked for in the question.